# Call Variables in Cplex

Tags: cplex

I want to call a Cplex variable that one argument belongs to other:

```
{string} part = ...; // job indexed by n or p 
tuple Tpart
{
    int Demand;
    int Lotsize;
    int Maxsublots;
}
Tpart partCriteria[part] = ...;
```

Then I create a variable `jobC` belong to `part` and `partCriteria[part].Maxsublots`

but  it not correct

```
dvar float+ jobC[i in part, 1..partCriteria[part].Maxsublots];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPL arrays cannot have dimensions that depend on previous dimensions.

You could write

```
{string} part = {"A","B"}; // job indexed by n or p 
tuple Tpart
{
    int Demand;
    int Lotsize;
    int Maxsublots;
}
Tpart partCriteria[part] = [<1,1,1>,<2,2,2>];

int maxsublots=max(i in part) partCriteria[i].Maxsublots;

dvar float+ jobC[i in part, j in 1..maxsublots];

subject to
{

}
```